# How config the single page site module

Tags: 8, navigation

I have installed the [Single Page Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) module and I was follow the instructions but still don't works for me.

the module conf:

Menu: main

Menu class/id = #block-mainnavigation

Menu item selector = ""

Title: "Home"

Tag: h2

check: homepage

---

I have one item of my main menu called : "servicios", link to #servicios"

---

In my `page--front.html.twig`

i have a section with a element `<h2 name="servicios">Nuestros Servicios</h2>`

but don't works

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found a best way to do a one page menu , using [link attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes) for add exceptions to the any menu item, and i used [jquery one page nav](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) than with a simple reference to the menu, works perfectly.